# ConTeXt: Align \frame in margin header to get vertical rule in top margin

Tags: header-footer, context, frame

In `ConTeXt` I'm looking to make this `LaTeX` `kaobook` header.
[image]

I used `\showframe` to appreciate the layout elements and what happened to them while changing their dimensions:

```
\showframe

\setuppapersize[A4]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,location=none]
\setuplayout[
%  top=12mm,
%  topdistance=0mm,
  topspace=12mm,
  header=4.4mm,
  headerdistance=11mm,
  footdistance=0mm,
  footer=0mm,
  bottomdistance=0mm,
  bottom=27.4mm,
  leftedge=24.8mm,
  edgedistance=0mm,
  margin=47.7mm,
  leftmargindistance=0mm,
  width=107mm,
  rightmargindistance=6.2mm,
%  rightedgedistance=0mm,
  rightedge=24.3mm,
]

\setupheadertexts[margin]
[]
[{\getmarking[sectionnumber]} {\getmarking[section]} {\pagenumber}]
[{\framed[frame=on,width=14mm,height=4.4mm,align={outer,low}]{\pagenumber}} 
{\getmarking[chapternumber]} {\getmarking[chapter]}]
[]
```

To get

[image]

The page number is framed (I was thinking of using the option `frame=off,rightfram=on`). In what corresponds to the `header margin` this happens if I change to `\framed[frame=on,width=20mm`

[image]

I don't know how far I am from getting something similar to the header of the first figure. What is missing to get to something like this?

Comment: I will not have time to answer now, but to get it clear: Is it the vertical bar that should run to the top of the page that is the whole thing? Or is it also something else?

Comment: Also I have a problem with the horizontal position of the pagenumber, chatpter number and chapter name in the header margin. I made pagenumber framed to see what happend changing `\framed[width=]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can play with `offset` in the frame, but maybe, to also get the vertical line, it is easiest to use a MetaFun graphic. Here we use a simple one that only draws a line and then fakes the bounding box (the 0.5pt is the default width of the line, as far as I remember). The 3cm was chosen so that it surely sticks out at the top.

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided,
   location=none]

\setuplayout[
  topspace=12mm,
  header=\lineheight,% Changed
  headerdistance=11mm,
  footdistance=0mm,
  footer=0mm,
  bottomdistance=0mm,
  bottom=27.4mm,
  leftedge=24.8mm,
  edgedistance=0mm,
  margin=47.7mm,
  leftmargindistance=0mm,
  width=107mm,
  rightmargindistance=6.2mm,
  rightedge=24.3mm,
]

\startuseMPgraphic{thebar}
  draw (0,-StrutDepth) -- (0,3cm) withcolor darkred ;
  setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare shifted (-0.5,0) xysized (0.5pt,LineHeight) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\setupheadertexts
  [margin]
  []
  [{\getmarking[sectionnumber]} {\getmarking[section]} {\pagenumber}]
  [{\pagenumber\space\space \useMPgraphic{thebar}\space\space \getmarking[chapternumber]\space {\it \getmarking[chapter]}}]
  []

\starttext

\dorecurse{10}{
  \startchapter[title={Foo}]
  \dorecurse{20}{
    \startsection[title={Bar}]
      \samplefile{knuth}
    \stopsection
  }
  \stopchapter
}

\stoptext
```

On top of page 24 it looks like this:

[image: top of page 24]

Some further comments:

- Remove the `withcolor darkred` if you do not want the line colored.
- I changed your `header=4.4mm` into `header=\lineheight`. That was just a suggestion.
- The horizontal position of your header will depend on the content, since the content by default is aligned to the right.
- If the content is wider than the width of the margin (that will happen if you have a long chapter title), it will move out to the left.

If you get any further problems, I suggest that you ask a new question about that.